# Archivo gpedit.bat fue ejecutado y no entiendo mucho lo que hizo en mi sistema

Tags: windows, batch

Tengo Windows 10 Home y un compañero descargó un archivo (gpedit.bat) junto con un archico de texto (List.txt)

Lo ejecutó y ahora no funciona el internet y está exagerademente lenta la computadora. Antes de tomar decisiones quiero entender que hace el código del archivo gpedit.bat que ejecutó. Lo dejo a continuación:

---

### gpedit.bat =

@echo off 
pushd "%~dp0"

dir /b %SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy-ClientExtensions-Package~3*.mum >List.txt

dir /b %SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy-ClientTools-Package~3*.mum >>List.txt

for /f %%i in ('findstr /i . List.txt 2^>nul') do dism /online /norestart /add-package:"%SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\%%i"

### pause

Por lo visto en el código itera sobre los elementos del archico List.txt que contenía lo siguiente:

### List.txt =

Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy-ClientExtensions-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~en-US~10.0.18362.1.mum
Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy-ClientExtensions-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.18362.1.mum
Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy-ClientExtensions-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-MX~10.0.18362.1.mum
Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy-ClientExtensions-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.18362.1.mum
Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy-ClientTools-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~en-US~10.0.18362.1.mum
Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy-ClientTools-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-ES~10.0.18362.1.mum
Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy-ClientTools-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~es-MX~10.0.18362.1.mum
Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy-ClientTools-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.18362.1.mum

---

Si alguien me dice que hace el código gpedit.bat le agradecería mucho

Comment: Renato, si solucioné tu duda, por favor recueda aceptar mi respuesta. Cualquier otra duda de Windows estaré feliz de ayudarte. Saludos,

Comment: ¿Solucionó tu problema, @renato-balcazar? Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si tu problema se solucionó. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido a la comunidad.
El archivo .bat que mencionas sirve para habilitar el Editor de Políticas de Grupo (Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc)) en Windows 10 Home Edition.

Pude encontrar el mismo archivo que mencionas en el método #2 del siguiente [tutorial](https://www.itechtics.com/enable-gpedit-windows-10-home/).

Lo que hace el archivo es modificar los registros de Windows para habilitar esta característica que está desactivada en tu versión de Windows.

Espero haber resuelto tu pregunta.

Comment: Los problemas que estas teniendo tal vez sean efecto de otras causas y debiesen ser investigadas particularmente; pero dado que el archivo .bat solo interactúa con registros del group policy, dificilmente podrían causar fallas como las que mencionas. No está demas proponerte utilizar la herramienta de recuperación de windows para hacer un rollback a una fecha previa al cambio, o hacer un fresh start con tu Windows, sin necesidad de perder archivos. Si quieres hacer un analisis más fino, te invito a ver el administrador de tareas para encontrar que procesos estan ocupando tus recursos.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Si creo que al final voy a hacer una restauración del sistema aunque implique perder mis aplicaciones y programas instalados.

Comment: renato, no es necesario que restaures perdiendo los archivos. Windows 10 tiene 3 tipos de restauración, uno de los cuales corresponde al fresh start sin perder archivos; sin embargo, los registros de windows y archivos del sistema se restaurarán. esa denería ser tu opción si es que no quieres perder tus archivos.